# How to satisfy Accessibility in PageSpeed Insight with a link that contains both an image and text?

Tags: accessibility, pagespeed-insights

PageSpeed Insights keeps penalising me on Accessibiliy for having a button (anchor link) with an image and text. The anchor tag has an `aria-label` with the same value as the text inside the link.

Here's the HTML:

```
<style>
    a {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: #000;
        color:#fff;
    }
</style>

<a aria-label="Call us now" href="tel:123456">
    <img src="images/phone.png" width="20" height="20">
    Call us now
</a>
```

I've tried the following solutions:

| SOLUTION | Accessibility penalty |
| --- | --- |
| Image has no alt-attribute | [-9] Image elements do not have [alt] attributes (plus extra SEO penalty of [-8] |
| Image has alt-attribute | [-7] Elements with visible text labels do not have matching accessible names. |
| Image has alt-attribute with value matching aria-label | [-8] Elements with visible text labels do not have matching accessible names. **AND** Image elements have [alt] attributes that are redundant text. |

I don't want to introduce hacks to fix the issue (e.g. add the image via css using a pseudo class, a background-image or a list-style-image) as I think this is a fairly normal use-case that should just be ok. But maybe I'm wrong? Is this a shortcoming of PageSpeed Insights or should I do this differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to repeat things and you already have the label in the link.

So it should either say the image is a decorative and so no need for it to be labeled by setting `alt=""`:

```html
<a href="tel:123456">
    <img src="images/phone.png" width="20" height="20" alt="">
    Call us now
</a>
```

Or give the image an `alt` label:

```html
<a href="tel:123456">
    <img src="images/phone.png" width="20" height="20" alt="telephone icon">
    Call us now
</a>
```

Comment: Your first solution feels wrong, but it is indeed accepted by PageSpeed Insights as the preferred solution. An empty attribute actually solves the issue... Using the alt tag to describe the image (so using it properly) results in a penalty (see my 2nd solution in the table).

Comment: Both ways solve this: https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-www-tunetheweb-com-experiments-alttext/44gqxp8rkg?form_factor=mobile

Please provide the code for your second solution (or a demo page) and I can maybe explain why it's still flagging it.

Comment: @Jerry Re:"first solution feels wrong" <- Nothing wrong about it. Skipping [decorative icons](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/images/decorative/) using `alt=""` is considered standard (best) practice. If you already have relevant text ("Call us now") then labeling the icon does nothing but slow down the screen reader. The user doesn't need to hear "link telephone icon call us now"

Comment: That's a very good point. It does feel that adding empty attributes is just done to satisfy these validators like such as PageSpeed Insights. It doesn't contribute to anything else I think.

Comment: @Jerry There's a tangible difference between a missing `alt` vs an empty `alt=""`. If `alt` is missing, some screen readers will read the `src` file/url out loud (_not_ skip the image). Setting an empty `alt=""` is the only way to guarantee that the screen reader skips the image.

Comment: `alt=""` may look weird initially and it is a bit of a special case. It's a well-known, well-used, shortcut for hiding the image from a11y tree (it's basically short hand for `aria-hidden=true` but has been supported for even longer than that). It's also good practice to ALWAYS include an `alt` attribute to remind you to consider a11y and only explicitly set it to the empty string if you really mean it. In fact it's technically invalid HTML to have an `<img>` element without an `alt` and HTML validators will insist you add one (even if it is the empty one).

Answer (score 0):

Barry Pollard's answer at the top is correct, here's my summary of the valuable input from both Barry and tdy (and to fix my earlier incorrect summary). Hopefully this is useful to anybody.

1. "aria-label can be used in cases where text that could label the element is not visible." (source: [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-label))
2. The first rule of ARIA is not to use it if you don't have to. (source: [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#firstrule))
3. The ALT attribute is a **required** part of the IMG tag. An IMG tag without it is invalid HTML (source: [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img)). An empty ALT-attribute will prevent screen readers from reading out the image URL.

Only use aria-labels and values inside the image's ALT-attribute if it really benefits the accessibility of the content. Often ALT-attributes on UI icons for example will just worsen the experience on a screenreader. A good tip is to run the page through a screenreader to hear it yourself.

Here are 3 possible situations that will all score **full points on Accessibility**:

### Link with image but no visible text

**With aria-label, image tag has empty ALT- attribute**

```
<a aria-label="Call us now" href="tel:45678">
    <img src="images/just-phone.png" width="40" height="40" alt="">
</a>
```

### Link with image but no visible text

**Without aria-label, with text in ALT-attribute**

```
<a href="tel:45678">
    <img src="images/just-phone.png" width="40" height="40" alt="Call button">
</a>
```

### Link with image and text

**No aria-label, empty ALT-attribute has text between anchor tags**

```
<a href="tel:45678">
    <img src="images/just-phone.png" width="40" height="40" alt="">
    Call us now
</a>
```

Thanks [Barry Pollard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2144578/barry-pollard) and [tdy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13138364/tdy) for your excellent help!

Comment: These examples are not considered good practice. Over-labeling is a common accessibility trap. I suggest trying them out with a screen reader to see what the end user would actually experience. Consider hearing so many extraneous words over the course of a whole page "link telephone icon call us now link twitter icon tweet us now link facebook icon share this page on facebook link profile picture go to user profile link house icon go to home page link gear icon go to settings ... ... ..."

Comment: @tdy That's a very good point.

Comment: +1 to @tdy 's comment. The first rule of ARIA (https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#firstrule) is not to use it if you don't have to. There is a well-known, well-accepted ways of labelling this (with image `alt` and/or with text) without resorting to `aria-label`. The 1st example means the image alt text is overridden and will likely not be used, so would be confusing to have that specified when it is not used. The 2nd isn't very good as it doesn't explain what the link does (dials a number) - though arguably sighted users also have to guess. The 3rd may indeed be overly verbose.